# Weblogic WLST classpath

Tags: weblogic-10.x, wlst

When I run the WLST script .sh script to set the env as follows why can't I see the updated path when I do echo?

```
[linbox2 bin]$ ./setWLSEnv.sh 
CLASSPATH=/directory/ols_wls/patch_wlss1032/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/directory/ols_wls/patch_wls1032/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/directory/ols_wls/patch_oepe1032/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/directory/ols_wls/patch_ocm1031/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/directory/ols_wls/jrockit_160_14_R27.6.5-32/lib/tools.jar:/directory/ols_wls/utils/config/10.3/config-launch.jar:/directory/ols_wls/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/directory/ols_wls/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/directory/ols_wls/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.2.0.jar:/directory/ols_wls/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/webservices.jar:/directory/ols_wls/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.0/lib/ant-all.jar:/directory/ols_wls/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.0.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar:

PATH=/directory/ols_wls/wlserver_10.3/server/bin:/directory/ols_wls/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.0/bin:/directory/ols_wls/jrockit_160_14_R27.6.5-32/jre/bin:/directory/ols_wls/jrockit_160_14_R27.6.5-32/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2_11/bin/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/directory/wls_olwcs/jdk160_14_R27.6.5-32/bin:/directory/ccanywhere81/bin:/directory/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/client_1/bin

Your environment has been set.
[linbox2 bin]$ export CLASSPATH
[linbox2 bin]$ export PATH
[linbox2 bin]$ echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2_11/bin/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/directory/wls_olwcs/jdk160_14_R27.6.5-32/bin:/directory/ccanywhere81/bin:/directory/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/client_1/bin
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to run the script in your current shell.

```
$. ./setWLSEnv.sh
```

Note the the two periods and the space between them. The way you are running the script now, the path is updated in the shell created for the script which closes once the script finishes running.

Adding the period before the script will run the script in your current shell.

Answer (score 0):

The export commands you have used after setWLSEnv.sh is going to invalidate the settings that made by the script. Better you run the script setWLSEnv.sh and then use echo $PATH. Hope this will help.